# Looping access database

Tags: vb.net

I have a access database containing the following:

```
SEG,AMK,101427Y,EG3902,EG3902-G1
SEG,AMK,101427Y,EGS650,EGS650-G1
SEG,AMK,103852S,EG3901,EG3901-G1
SEG,AMK,103852S,EG3904,EG3904-G1
SEG,AMK,103852S,EGS104,EGS104-G1
SEG,AMK,103852S,EGS650,EGS650-G1
SEG,AMK,106581C,EG3901,EG3901-G1
SEG,AMK,106581C,EG3902,EG3902-G1
SEG,AMK,111713M,EG3901,EG3901-G1
SEG,AMK,111713M,EG3902,EG3902-G1
```

I wanna loop to get: example,

```
EG3091 - 103852S
       - 106581C
       - 111713M
```

Means a list with Distinct Module codes and the students taking the module to come out like the example I've listed.

I have retrieved the distinct module list from my database using SQL command already.

anyone teach me how should I go about doing it?

Can I use For loop? if yes, how can I say if the student matches the module?

Comment: Why don't you just query for it like :`SELECT student FROM yourTable WHERE module = 'EG3091'`

Comment: Was thinking same thing

Comment: i cant list out all the modulecodes as there were more thann 30k of them. im aware of the where clause with specified criteria, but now i  cant specify all of them.